# Spark: How to update a particular element in the list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have orders in a JSON, the order has a list of products and products contains a list of product colors.

Lst's say an order with ID 1, has products with ID 1 and 2. And product 1 has product_color IDs with 1 and 2.

Something as below:

```
|order_id|order_json                      |prodcut_id|product_color_json|
|1       |[1,[[1,//so on], [[2,//so on]]]]|1         |[1,,,,1]           |
|1       |[1,[[1,//so on], [[2,//so on]]]]|1         |[2,,,,1]           |
```

Now, I have an update for a particular product. In our case say a product with ID 1 got an update.

**Now I want to update order_json with a newly updated list of product with ID 1 while keeping the remaining products in the order JSON.**

I am trying to avoid using UDF function.

The schema for my data frame is

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- order_json: struct (nullable = true)
 |--  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- weight: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- product_color: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- product_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- product_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- product_color_json: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- product_id: integer (nullable = true)
```

The sample existing order json

```
{
   "id":1,
   "products":[
      {
         "id":101,
         "name":"scooter",
         "description":"Open",
         "weight":2.14,
         "created_at":1594512000000,
         "updated_at":1594512000001,
         "product_color":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "color":"green",
               "created_at":1594512000000,
               "updated_at":1594512000001,
               "product_id":101
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "color":"green",
               "created_at":1594512000000,
               "updated_at":1594512000000,
               "product_id":101
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":102,
         "name":"scooter",
         "description":"Open",
         "weight":2.14,
         "created_at":1594512000000,
         "updated_at":1594512000001,
         "product_color":[
            {
               "id":2,
               "color":"green",
               "created_at":1594512000000,
               "updated_at":1594512000000,
               "product_id":102
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Sample JSON for the change in product_color with ID 1. The color changed from green to blue.

```
{
 "id":1,
 "color":"blue",
 "created_at":1594512000000,
 "updated_at":1594512000002,
 "product_id":101
}
```

New update JSON

```
{
   "id":1,
   "products":[
      {
         "id":101,
         "name":"scooter",
         "description":"Open",
         "weight":2.14,
         "created_at":1594512000000,
         "updated_at":1594512000001,
         "product_color":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "color":"blue",
               "created_at":1594512000000,
               "updated_at":1594512000002,
               "product_id":101
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "color":"green",
               "created_at":1594512000000,
               "updated_at":1594512000000,
               "product_id":101
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":102,
         "name":"scooter",
         "description":"Open",
         "weight":2.14,
         "created_at":1594512000000,
         "updated_at":1594512000001,
         "product_color":[
            {
               "id":2,
               "color":"green",
               "created_at":1594512000000,
               "updated_at":1594512000000,
               "product_id":102
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Spark: 2.4.5
Language: Scala

Comment: can you also add your expected json ??

Comment: @Srinivas thanks for taking a look. Have updated the information with an expected JSON

Comment: where is ```prodcut_id``` in your sample json ??

Comment: It's a part of product_color JSON ```{
 "id":1,
 "color":"blue",
 "created_at":1594512000000,
 "updated_at":1594512000002,
 "product_id":101
}```